# Make my Asp.Net application support all browser

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, performance

I have an asp.net application which was initially designed for support only in IE(Internet Explorer). Now i want to convert that application which will support all the latest browser, 
Basically it was developed Asp.net, CSS and Javascript(Specific for IE).Is there any easy way to convert because I have only 1 week time to Submit if i failed then i need to report whether it is possible or not?

Comment: what part of it is failing? We need ALOT more information. Specific programming questions would help

Comment: Yes, as Matt said, you will have to address each case of incompatibility specifically as there is no one-fits-all solution.

Comment: have you ever tried on the other browser? In what part, you see errors?

Comment: Usually people develop for everything except for IE... you did inverse! Epic win.

Comment: Good luck with that! [Try this link](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/15-techniques-and-tools-for-cross-browser-css-coding).

Comment: @BonusKun, I tried in Mozilla and Chrome the page is opening but not a single javascript or function or events are not working. not even my login button.

Comment: @AndreaTurri I do not aggree with you. There are a lot of intranet websites that are developed especially for IE. Because all the computers in a domain at certain companies use IE and there is no way they allow other than the one they installed...

Comment: @SantoshSahu is it possible to see some code.. Because this sounds very strange.

Comment: @Jordy van Eijk you don't need to do the expert with me for that comment! I was just kidding. Do the expert answering questions.

Comment: @SantoshSahu, try Firebird and Chrome's Java Console to see what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the quick answer - it will probably take you longer than a week :)

The best thing to do is view your website in different browsers and see what the problems are. You have been a bit vague in your question, but you could be looking at having to fix UI issues and possbily JavaScript problems.

Which version of IE are you supporting? You need to take this into account since developing for cross browser support means not only fixing problems for modern browsers, but making sure that older browsers are not broken.

This is a very open-ended question, and the best suggestion I have is the above. There is no way to convert an application to magically be cross-browser compatible. It's going to be a manual job unfortunately.

Most importantly, you need to to measure how bad things are in other browsers before you can get a plan together of what it will take to fix.

Comment: +1 I completely agree with Jason.You need to check each and every aspect with what browsers are you dealing with and fix them according to that.

Comment: I tried in Mozilla and Chrome the page(means Login UI) is opening but not a single javascript, function not even events are not working. not even my login button.

Comment: In Mozilla (Firebug) and Chrome's dev tools, there should be a `Console` tab. Click on that tab and try those pages again. If there are any JavaScript errors then they could appear in the `Console` output.